# Creating Mock JMX Servers and Beans in Groovy

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, jmx

We are monitoring a custom application with extensive custom MBeans and attributes. We've been functionally testing for a long time with servers in a lab, but now we want to create proper unit tests that don't rely on actual remote connections.

On my own, I simply have not been able to figure out how to use Groovy JMX builder to start a local MBeanServer, and expose local mbeans with a list of attributes and operations.

Would anyone be willing to provide an example of such a mockup?  The existing examples I've found for jmxbuilder don't get me there, but it looks like it should be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example of a Spock test

- Exporting a groovy bean into JMX
- Importing and using this bean

The code :

```
class JMXSpec extends Specification {

    class MyBean {
        def property
    }

    def "launch and test a mbean"() {
        given: "a mbean exported"

            def jmx = new JmxBuilder()
            jmx.export {
                // Export every properties/methods of 'MyBean' 
                // under 'Groovy.Test:name=MyBean'
                bean(
                    target:new MyBean(property:"test"),
                    name:"Groovy.Test:name=MyBean"
                )

            }

        and: "a mbean imported from the local server"
            def mbean = new GroovyMBean(ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer(), 
                "Groovy.Test:name=MyBean")
        expect:
            "test" == mbean.Property
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, this might be exactly what I need, thanks!  Learning a lot here.  When you do jmx.export of a bean, you "target" an instance of any pojo or pogo, and give the name, very cool!  Can I get an "MBeanServerConnection" object and then use QueryNames?   Also, I noticed you used Capital P on mbean.Property, and it works, while .property doesn't work, what's happening there?  I've never had to use proper case in mbean attribute names before.

Comment: I don't know for the capital. It's the way mbean attribute are registered, but I don't really know why. You can use a GroovyMBean with a `MBeanServerConnection` but it doesn't support queries: you have to execute your query, and then create a GroovyMBean with the name found

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I use (example in Java, not Groovy....)

```
/**
 * Creates a new visible MBeanServer
 * @param name The MBeanServer's default domain name
 * @param xregPlatform true to register all known PlatformManagedObject in the created MBeanServer, false otherwise
 * @return the new MBeanServer
 */
public static synchronized MBeanServer createMBeanServer(final String name, final boolean xregPlatform) {
    MBeanServer mbs = getLocalMBeanServer(name);
    if(mbs==null) {
        mbs = MBeanServerFactory.createMBeanServer(name);
    }
    if(xregPlatform) {
        registerPlatformManagedObjects(mbs);
    }
    return mbs;
}
```

See my [JMXHelper](https://github.com/nickman/heliosutils/blob/master/src/main/java/com/heliosapm/utils/jmx/JMXHelper.java) for details on those other methods.

Comment: Thank you for this piece. It certainly helps conceptually.  Do you create any beans and attributes?

Comment: I am still hoping that a Groovy developer will be able to provide a complete solution to this someday in Groovy. I think it's a pretty common use case.

Answer (score 0):

Also, for posterity, here is a slightly modified example mimicking the common "queryNames" method...

```
import groovy.jmx.builder.JmxBuilder
import spock.lang.Specification
import javax.management.ObjectName
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory


class SandboxJmxBuilderSpec extends Specification {
    class MyBean {
        def property
    }

    def "launch and test a mbean"() {
        given: "a mbean exported"

        def jmx = new JmxBuilder()
        jmx.export {
            // Export every properties/methods of 'MyBean'
            // under 'Groovy.Test:name=MyBean'
            bean(
                    target:new MyBean(property:"test"),
                    name:"Groovy.Test:name=MyBean"
            )

        }

        and: "a mbean imported from the local server"
        def mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer()
        def queryString = "Groovy.Test:name=MyBean"
        def discovery = mbs.queryNames(new ObjectName(queryString), null)

        expect:
        "test" == new GroovyMBean(mbs, discovery[0]).Property
    }
}
```